# cannot load such file -- nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, railsinstaller-windows

I installed Ruby on Rals using RailsInstaller for Windows (I have Windows 10)
when I try to run the first application, I have an error after rails server:

```
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:29:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/loofah-2.0.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.1/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:32:in `<module:TextHelper>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb:29:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:50:in `<module:Helpers>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:7:in `<module:LegacyAssetTagHelper>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:6:in `<module:Rails>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:4:in `<module:Sprockets>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/legacy_asset_tag_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:45:in `<module:Helper>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:7:in `<module:Rails>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:6:in `<module:Sprockets>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.1/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from C:/Sites/todo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix it?What are the reasons of errors "cannot load such file"?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of linking to an image, please edit your question and then copy/paste the text in. That's for several reasons: 1) we can then copy/paste text out of it to do searches on the error messages 2) links to external sites go stale very quickly, and we want Stack Overflow questions to last forever (in case somebody else has the same problem as you, they can find this question and use the answers to help them solve it).

Answer (score 0):

Try running `$ gem install nokogiri` in Cygwin or whatever CLI you're using in your environment. This should install the `nokogiri` gem for you and (hopefully) cause the error to disappear.